# Entity Framework problem in new Entity Inheritance

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Could someone with some good knowledge answer this question please. Im having a problem with the schema in my Students.aspx page. I have done the [walkthrough](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-%E2%80%93-getting-started-part-6), but I get an error and I have copied the edmx file from the sample into my application and I still get the error. This is the error:

> 'EnrollmentDate' is not a member of
>   type 'SchoolModel.Person' in the
>   currently loaded schemas. Near simple
>   identifier, line 6, column 4.

I have also created a new EntityDataSource and I have the same problem. The sample works fine but I can't seem to get the EnrollmentDate and HireDate fields to be part of the 'SchoolModel.Person' Entity. The part which is Upto setting the EntityTypeFilter then I run the app and I get problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're following the example on MSDN. By the end of the example, the fields `EnrollmentDate` and `HireDate` are no longer on the `SchoolModel.Person` class, they're on the subclasses `SchoolModel.Instructor` and `SchoolModel.Student`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while going through that walkthrough. The solution: Just delete the old EntityDataSource control on the page, put new EntityDataSource, configure it as given in walkthrough (with entity set name: People; EntityTypeFilter: Student or instructor), And every thing works as it should!!

Faraz

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have missed one or more EDS controls when you added the EntityTypeFilter attributes.  Are you sure all your EDS controls that access students or instructors have EntityTypeFilter="Student" or EntityTypeFilter="Instructor"?

Comment: I have done it the way the tutorial showed me I also have set the EntityTypeFilter to Student